# How do I display values on top of Shinobi bar chart for android

Tags: android, bar-chart, shinobi

How do I display values on top of a bar chart using the shinobi library in android

Answer (score 2):

The `AnnotationsManager`, specifically the `addTextAnnotation` method, is the solution that you are looking for. You can use this method to add any string to the chart at any X and Y position, in terms of data.

There is a [How-To guide](http://www.shinobicontrols.com/docs/ShinobiControls/ShinobiChartsAndroid/1.6.0/Premium/Normal/user-guide/how-to-add-annotations.html) about Annotations at the ShinobiControls website. This How-To guide, along with an accompanying sample app, is also included in the download bundle.

Disclaimer: I work for ShinobiControls.